# ndk-build "member ... in archive is not an object"

Tags: android, aes, android-ndk

I use this AES library (in C language),
http://gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/AES/aes-src-16-04-07.zip

I follow this page and use the commds mentioned to compile *libaes.a*,
http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/aes-encrypt-decrypt-in-c-687368.html

```
gcc -c -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer aescrypt.c aeskey.c aestab.c aes_modes.c
ar rcs libaes.a *.o
```

I can compile and run my program using the *libaes.a* without problem.

However if use **ndk-build** to compile my program (indeed modified a little),
I always get this error message and fail to compile...

**"...member *aes_modes.o* in archive is not an object..."**

what's wrong with that file?
Or what's wrong with the process?

my Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libaes
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libaes.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES :=\
    /android-ndk-r6b/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include\
    /android-ndk-r6b/samples/hello-jni/jni/libaes
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libaes
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: my computer is "Windows 7, 64bit". Does that have something to do with my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've a feeling that you compiled aes with native tools (x86) and using it as prebuild library. I've tried this `Android.mk` and it works:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := aes
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := aes/aescrypt.c aes/aeskey.c aes/aestab.c aes/aes_modes.c

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES        := jni/aes
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES  := aes
LOCAL_MODULE            := hello-jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := hello-jni.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Just unzip `aes-src-16-04-07.zip` into `jni/aes`. I think it is better to use ndk build system because it can set all necesary options.

And hello-jni.c (just in case):

```
#include <aes.h>

void test() {
    aes_init();
}
```

Comment: It works. Thanks.  But still got a problem. I compiled my program with cygwin and encrypted files on PC (Windows 7, 64bit). Then I push the encrypted files onto SDcard, decrypted them on Android. Unfortunately the decrypted file wasn't readable, the same problem as this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937715/android-aes-in-c     why?

Comment: Is uint_8t the same on PC and Android ?

Comment: The first though was - maybe it is the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) problem? If it so, try to switch bytes in the word.